# Windows software to move any window between multiple monitors (screens) by using keys BUT without resizing the moved window

Tags: windows-7, window-manager, keyboard-shortcuts, multi-monitor

I have a multiscreen computer:

[image]

and I use [WindowPad](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/19990-windowpad-window-moving-tool/) to **move (arrange) any window** on the screen, and this program is too capable of moving them **between monitors** by pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The **issue** is: the moved window is **re-scaled** (resized) to the corresponding size of the new monitor, as you can see in the two images below. From a 1280x1024 screen:

[image]

to a 1920x1200 screen:

[image]

Note the *resized Putty SSH* console window. That is not what I want.

Moving windows without using the mouse is extremely useful for me, but I have not been capable to find a practical way to do this without resizing that window.
The **pop-up menu** that most windows have is not valid, because, even when I can move the windows, this moving is too slow (I prefer to use the mouse in that case):

[image]

<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> do not work on my Windows 7 SP1, I don´t know why.

Ideas are welcome.

Comment: Without rescaling, how would a maximized window on screen 1 fit when you move it to screen 6, or do you want the window to span multiple monitors?

Comment: You are right, @Timmy, I did not think about it. Fortunately, I have found the solution: I have modified WindowPad source code successfully, and now it moves any window without rescaling it; and maximized windows keep maximized between monitors. I am researching to know if my solution should be published here at SuperUser, or at any other forum like StackOverFlow (as long as it is a programming response). Just give me a few days and I will post here my method.

Comment: Timmy, I have added my answer here. It is based on the source modification. I will add precompiled `.exe` to AutoHotKey forums repositories as long as I will know how to do it. I suppose SuperUser has no storage for files, so I can't think about another way.

Comment: Nice work! I think leaving a code here is fine, as long asn there are clear instructions on how to execute it. You could also store it at Github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the original [WindowPad](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/19990-windowpad-window-moving-tool/) source [code](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=199) to not resize windows when moving or changing monitor.

These are the steps:

- Download from the link above and unzip.
- To **disable resizing of windows when moving** edit `\source\WindowPad.ahk` to change (Windows Notepad is OK):

  ```
  ; Move and resize.
  WinMove,,, newx, newy, neww, newh
  ```

to (note the comments with `;` character) :

```
        ; Move and resize.
;        WinMove,,, newx, newy, neww, newh
        WinMove,,, newx, newy, w, h
```

and change:

```
wp_CalcNewSizeAndPosition:
    ; Calculate desired size.
    neww := restore_w != "" ? restore_w : Round(monWidth * widthFactor)
    newh := restore_h != "" ? restore_h : Round(monHeight * heightFactor)
```

to (we keep some lines by using comments too) :

```
wp_CalcNewSizeAndPosition:
    ; Calculate desired size.
;    neww := restore_w != "" ? restore_w : Round(monWidth * widthFactor)
;    newh := restore_h != "" ? restore_h : Round(monHeight * heightFactor)
    neww := w
    newh := h
```

- To **disable resizing of windows when changing screen** edit `\source\WindowPad.ahk` to change:

`; Calculate new size.
if (wp_IsResizable()) {
    w := Round(w*(mdw/msw))
    h := Round(h*(mdh/msh))
}`

to:

```
    ; Calculate new size.
    if (wp_IsResizable()) {
;        w := Round(w*(mdw/msw))
;        h := Round(h*(mdh/msh))
        w := w
        h := h
    }
```

(a rather ridiculous change this one, but it helps understanding the modification's sense)

- Now you have your .ahk file that you can run if you have installed [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Or **compile it to `.exe`** by using the same program (`Convert .ahk to .exe`).
- And a minor enhancement: These lines here are preventing to put your own **icon in the tray** (you can choose it when compiling the `.ahk` file, but it will not appear there):

.

```
if A_IsCompiled  ; Load icons from my custom WindowPad.exe.
{
; Default icon is 32x32, so doesn't look good in the tray.
Menu, Tray, Icon, %A_ScriptFullPath%, 2
}
else if (A_LineFile = A_ScriptFullPath)
{   ; Set the tray icon, but only if not included in some other script.
wp_SetTrayIcon(true)
; Use OnMessage to catch "Suspend Hotkeys" or "Pause Script"
; so the "disabled" icon can be used.
OnMessage(0x111, "WM_COMMAND")
}
```

so just comment them all:

```
;    if A_IsCompiled  ; Load icons from my custom WindowPad.exe.
;    {
;        ; Default icon is 32x32, so doesn't look good in the tray.
;        Menu, Tray, Icon, %A_ScriptFullPath%, 2
;    }
;    else if (A_LineFile = A_ScriptFullPath)
;    {   ; Set the tray icon, but only if not included in some other script.
;        wp_SetTrayIcon(true)
;        ; Use OnMessage to catch "Suspend Hotkeys" or "Pause Script"
;        ; so the "disabled" icon can be used.
;        OnMessage(0x111, "WM_COMMAND")
;    }
```

and now you can compile your `.ahk` to a `.exe` that will have your preferred icon for the file and for the tray icon (every AutoHotKey icon in the tray has the same green `H` if not specified).

My compilation to .exe is working fantastic. Now WindowPad is the best program I have ever seen to move and arrange windows, even with multiple screens.

Please reports bugs if you find them.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need special software

Win+Shift+Left arrow: Move window to the monitor on the left
Win+Shift+Right arrow: Move window to the monitor on the right

Also, Windows-P opens the display switcher:

[image]

**Computer only** is the default option–and the name says it all.
**Duplicate** clones your screen to a connected secondary display, monitor or projector.
**Extend** expands the desktop so you can make room for extra windows.
**Projector only** turns off your laptop's LCD and turns the projector into your monitor

Comment: Win+Shift+Left/Right arrow are not working on my computer. And Windows+P is not valid, since I have 6 screens. Added info to original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) (non-free, Windows, GUI) to set up a keyboard shortcut to move a window to the next or previous monitor.

[image]

As Jan said, Windows 7 has some native shortcuts, which I don't use because I bind <kbd>Win</kbd> to left mouse click:

- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Left</kbd> to move a window to the left monitor
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> to move a window to the right monitor

Like you I have 6 monitors so I also need to move a window to the *bottom/top* in my case between monitors 3 and 4 and between monitors 5 and 6:

[image]

I saw that AHK might have some functions for it, e.g. [WindowPad](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/19990-windowpad-window-moving-tool/) and [WindowPadX](https://github.com/hoppfrosch/WindowPadX), but it's not clear to me how to set such a keyboard shortcut, so I asked the question here a while ago: [Move a window to the bottom/top monitor with a shortcut on Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7578/903)